# get runtime memory with Runtime Class

Tags: java

IDEA VMoptions: `-Xmx100m -Xms100m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags`

code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println(rt.maxMemory());
        System.out.println(rt.totalMemory());
        System.out.println(rt.freeMemory());
    }
```

Question:

1. From comments of source code, maxMemory is the max amount of memory JVM attempt to use, but why the output is smaller than 10MB? So what do these memory represents for?
2. From the output, Metaspace seems belonging to Heap. Why?
3. From the output, PSYoungGen+ParOldGen != 10MB configured in vm options `-Xmx100m -Xms100m`

output:

```
-XX:InitialHeapSize=104857600 -XX:MaxHeapSize=104857600 -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParallelGC 
objc[73147]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x108b194c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x108c5e4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
100663296
100663296
98035184
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 29696K, used 3078K [0x00000007bdf00000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 25600K, 12% used [0x00000007bdf00000,0x00000007be201b88,0x00000007bf800000)
  from space 4096K, 0% used [0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007bfc00000,0x00000007c0000000)
  to   space 4096K, 0% used [0x00000007bf800000,0x00000007bf800000,0x00000007bfc00000)
 ParOldGen       total 68608K, used 0K [0x00000007b9c00000, 0x00000007bdf00000, 0x00000007bdf00000)
  object space 68608K, 0% used [0x00000007b9c00000,0x00000007b9c00000,0x00000007bdf00000)
 Metaspace       used 3269K, capacity 4496K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 359K, capacity 388K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

I wrote a small program that outputs some memory statistics.

```
public class Memory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        System.out.println("Max memory");
        System.out.println(runtime.maxMemory());

        System.out.println("Total memory");
        System.out.println(runtime.totalMemory());

        System.out.println("Free memory");
        System.out.println(runtime.freeMemory());
    }
}
```

We can run this program with the command:

```
java -Xms16m -Xmx16m Memory.java
```

The "max memory" and "total memory" values should be identical.

Now let's try the command:

```
java -Xms16m -Xmx64m Memory.java
```

The value of "max memory" should be larger than the value of "total memory".

Why is this?

It's because the -Xms flag corresponds to "heap initial capacity" and the -Xmx flag corresponds to "heap max capacity". You can verify this fact by running the program with additional flags.

```
java -Xms16m -Xmx64m -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags Memory.java
```

To summarize what we have covered... we are using the -Xms and -Xmx flags to set the initial capacity of the heap and the maximum capacity of the heap. The small program included in this post behaves as expected, printing memory statistics that are consistent with the -Xms and -Xmx arguments.

The option `-Xms16m` is equivalent to `-Xms16M` and they both mean an initial heap capacity of 16 MB.

I hope this helps.

Comment: From output of the code, MaxMemory=PSYoungGen+ParOldGen, but PSYoungGen+ParOldGen  != -Xmx. So -Xmx(real heap size) consists of PSYoungGen+ParOldGen and part of Metaspace? and if so, how can we know how much percent of -Xmx will be used as (PSYoungGen+ParOldGen)?